# Is there anyway to get the Hotmail email contacts not the email hash in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, contacts, hotmail

How to get the Hotmail email contacts not the email hash in asp.net using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the email using delegate authentication. Here is the code snippet which I have done.

enter code here

```
public partial class DefaultPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Comma-delimited list of offers to be used.
    const string Offers = "Contacts.View";
    //Name of cookie to use to cache the consent token. 
    const string AuthCookie = "delauthtoken";

    // Initialize the WindowsLiveLogin module.
    static WindowsLiveLogin wll = new WindowsLiveLogin(true);

    protected WindowsLiveLogin.ConsentToken Token;

    protected string ConsentUrl;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the consent URL for the specified offers.
        ConsentUrl = wll.GetConsentUrl(Offers);

        HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        HttpCookie authCookie = req.Cookies[AuthCookie];

        // If the raw consent token has been cached in a site cookie, attempt to
        // process it and extract the consent token.
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            string t = authCookie.Value;
            Token = wll.ProcessConsentToken(t);
            getContacts(Token.DelegationToken,Token.LocationID);
            if ((Token != null) && !Token.IsValid())
            {
                Token = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void getContacts(string token, string lId)
    {
        long intlid = Int64.Parse(lId, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://livecontacts.services.live.com/users/@C@{0}/rest/livecontacts/contacts/", intlid));
        request.UserAgent = "Windows Live Data Interactive SDK";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "DelegatedToken dt=\"" + token + "\"");

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                //docNav = new XPathDocument(stream);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
              //  var contactStreamReponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

              //  XmlDocument contacts = new XmlDocument();
              //  contacts.LoadXml(contactStreamReponse);



                //Use the document. For example, display contacts.InnerXml.

              //  labelXml.Text = contacts.InnerXml;

                if (CheckBoxList1.Items.Count < 1)
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds.ReadXml(reader);
                    response.Close();
                    if (ds.Tables["Contact"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

                        for (int intC = 0; intC < ds.Tables["Email"].Rows.Count; intC++)
                        {
                            //Response.Write("FOr instance" + intC);

                            //Response.Write(ds.Tables["Email"].Rows[intC]["Address"].ToString());
                            ///Response.Write("<br>");
                            al.Add(ds.Tables["Email"].Rows[intC]["Address"].ToString());
                        }
                        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = al;
                        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO! Please don't just post a link with no real explanation - offer a summary, a snippet of code from the article, anything that shows some effort. It'll help anyone else who comes looking for this answer. =)